# Shorthand IF statements in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently I have a stored proc, which takes a string

```
@vari as varchar(30)
if @vari is null 
    SELECT * FROM TABLE 
else 
    SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE col = @vari
endif
```

is there any way to inline the if statement, thereby not declaring 2 select's just because of 1 param?

Comment: You can also do this with a case statement, it is not as short as the answers below but in some cases it is better.

Comment: I would not change your code, because in most cases sql will generate much better execution plan than combined `or` criteria.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE (@vari is null or col = @vari)
```

Comment: This works, but my next question: Why? Do the brackets only evaluate the 1st criteria as true then stop or...?

Comment: @Alex: It still evaluates both criteria, but because of the `or`, either one can be true for the row to be included in the result set.  If `@vari is null`, then every row will be returned because the first part is always true.  Otherwise, the only rows returned will be those matching the second part, `col = @vari`, which applies the filter.

Comment: Brackets are here because I have a habit of putting ORs in parentheses.

Comment: @mellamokb Thank you for the explanation, I was looking for a nice article about short-circuiting expressions in Sql Server but you saved me the effort ;-)

Comment: Do not rely on short-circuiting ... Those clauses could be evaluated in any order SQL Server sees fit.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `col` is never NULL, you can do this:

```
select *
from table
where col = isnull(@vari, col)
```